# Copy file with rpm in %pretrans

Tags: tar, rpm, rpmbuild

How can I get a .tgz file from rpmbuild's `SOURCES` directory within the `%pretrans` section to a target system using a RPM and extract it there?
I would have to do it in the `%pretrans` section because the .tgz file contains files that require other packages that are entered under `Requires` and I have no control over their contents.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Sources are used by `rpmbuild` to build binary rpm package. It happens on build system or on developer machine.

`%pretrans` is executed by `rpm` when **user** install/upgrade binary package on his machine. When user installs binary package, there is no way to fetch anything from SOURCES. That must be done during '%build' and '%install' phase. These are as well executed by `rpmbuild` on build system or on a developer machine.

You may want to check the basic Hello-world example https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#hello-world

If you need other packages for build time you specify them as `BuildRequires: some-package-needed-just-for-build`. E.g. `BuildRequires: make`.

When you use Mock for building then these BuildRequires are automatically downloaded and installed to chroot where the package is being built.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I can get the content of the .tgz into the rpm using `%install` section and `%file` section and place it in the right place using `install` commands in `%post` section. However, I would need the possibility already in the `%pretrans` section to make preparations before all rpms to be installed.